# How do I create a slash command in cogs?

Tags: python, discord, pycord

I want to make a slash command in the cogs, but the usual command `@commands.slash_command` does not work. I tried writing `@discord.slash_command` but it didn't help either.

Cog code:

```
#file "test.py" in ./cogs/test.py

import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Test(commands.Cog): 
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @discord.slash_command(name='ping')
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        pong = self.bot.latency
        await ctx.send(f'pong! `{round(pong*1000)} ms`')

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Test(bot))
```

Main file:

```
#file "main.py" in ./main.py

import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv

intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="t.", intents=intents, help_command=None)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    try:
        bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{cog}')
        print(f'[+] cog "{cog}.py" installed')
    except:
        print(f'[-] cog "{cog}.py" NOT installed')


load_dotenv()
token = os.getenv("TOKEN")
bot.run(token)
```

**I am using pycord,** and there is no `app_commands` module in this library

Comment: According to the Pycord docs (https://guide.pycord.dev/popular-topics/cogs), `discord.slash_command` should work. Please send all of your code.

Comment: @PythonNerd Is this all the code that is in the file, or do you need `main.py`?

Comment: Please share all of your code, including `main.py`.

Comment: @PythonNerd I attached the code from `main.py`. Any thoughts on why the slash command doesn't work?

Comment: I do not see anything wrong with your code; maybe an installation mistake? What is the exact error?

Comment: @PythonNerd The problem is that the command is not displayed anywhere and does not work, although there are no errors in the console and the code is quietly added to the bot

Comment: For the application commands to update on the user interface, you must quit the application and open it again or reload the web version.

Comment: @PythonNerd I tried to restart the discord, delete and add the bot again (with all permissions), but it did not help, the commands did not appear

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using `@discord.slash_command()` instead of `commands.slash_command()`. If you are using the commands module your command decorator should begin with `commands` instead of `discord`.

Comment: I've tried both options and nothing helps. the command does not appear anywhere